# SQL execution error: OAuth2 Access token request failed

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working in Snowflake with the new functionality [External Network Access](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/external-network-access/external-network-access-examples) that allows a function to connect to an external domain and make HTTP requests, in this use case I need to consult a domain of an API in the form of `domain.com:port/extra/url` as now I have been following the example to the letter of the documentation I linked above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NETWORK RULE network_rule_test 
MODE = EGRESS
  TYPE = HOST_PORT
  VALUE_LIST = ('domain.com:port/'); -- translation.googleapis.com


CREATE OR REPLACE SECURITY INTEGRATION sec_int_test
  TYPE = API_AUTHENTICATION
  AUTH_TYPE = OAUTH2
  OAUTH_CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
  OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret'
  OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'domain.com:port/url/token'
  -- OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
  -- OAUTH_ALLOWED_SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
  ENABLED = TRUE;


CREATE OR REPLACE SECRET secret_test
  TYPE = oauth2
  API_AUTHENTICATION = sec_int_test
  OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'refresh_token';


GRANT READ ON SECRET secret_test TO ROLE developer;
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL ACCESS INTEGRATION sec_int_test
  ALLOWED_NETWORK_RULES = (network_rule_test)
  ALLOWED_AUTHENTICATION_SECRETS = (secret_test)
  ENABLED = TRUE;

-- GRANT USAGE ON INTEGRATION sec_int_test TO ROLE developer;

-- USE ROLE developer;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION python_test(target_url STRING, params STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
HANDLER = 'get_url'
EXTERNAL_ACCESS_INTEGRATIONS = (sec_int_test)
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python',
            'requests')
SECRETS = ('cred' = secret_test )
AS
$$

import _snowflake
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
def get_url(sentence, language):
  token = _snowflake.get_oauth_access_token('cred')
  url = target_url
  params = {}
  response = session.get(url, params = params, json = None, headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token})
  return response.json()
$$;


-- GRANT USAGE ON FUNCTION python_test(string, string) TO ROLE user;

-- USE ROLE user;
SELECT python_test('domain.com:805/api/v1/Employee', '{}');
```

This is the code I have developed following the examples as closely as possible, the problem I encounter is that when I try to generate the `python_test` I get the error:

> SQL execution error: OAuth2 Access token request failed with error 'Connect to domain.com:813 timed out'

It seems as if the domain is not reachable or I am not configuring something correctly, this API is reachable and I am able to consume it locally, and my Snowflake server is reachable from the internet. What could be the cause of the lack of connection? Am I missing something obvious? Any advice or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be the network policy or rule that is causing the issue here?

Comment: You will need to have `OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT` also added as part of your integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, the answer was to use

```
OAUTH_GRANT = 'CLIENT_CREDENTIALS'
OAUTH_ALLOWED_SCOPES = ('[]')
```

In the security integration, then double check that my function didn't have any execution mistakes, in this case the parameters of the handler don't match with the snowflake function parameters so it will throw an error. It's important to indicate to appropiate grant mode, it seems that if you don't specify client it will try with the authorization flow, the documentation is not clear on the default methodology as far as i could see.